# WIndows Phone 10 Google Web Authorization Broker

Tags: authentication, windows-10-mobile

I'm faced with problem in my WP10. When i want to authorize by Google Web Authorization Broker i see this:
[image]
Whay does it mean? And how can i fix this? I check in lumia 950XL, 720 and broker show me this.
Best regards, Dmitriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was a problem which Google [fixed recently](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2467285/windows-mobile-google-sign-in-block-not-intentional-says-search-firm). It also caused Windows 10 Mobile users to be unable to sign-in to GMail account in Mail app.

Check again, should work now.